# SSRS Command Line SSRS to Zebra printer

Tags: reporting-services, rfid, zpl

I am using reporting services (SSRS) in my ERP solution, my goal now is send a command to a Zebra printer read the RFID.

Here an example of information "4711|2|RJ"

**ZPL command, 3 lines:**

^RFW,H

^FD4711|2|RJ

^FS

Maybe I can use RS.exe Utility (SSRS), but never used before.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I thought made it clear when I said My goal now is send a command to a Zebra printer read for RFID, so I can save/read data in the tag. Another approach is maybe use the Visual Basic language inside SSRS. Is that clear now ? Thanks.